# Custom context.html for Angular Karma test

Tags: angular, karma-runner, aframe

I need to modify `debug.html` and `context.html` for karma tests so that the required scripts are imported in the html head when running karma test in angular `ng t`.

The current import a library in the `<head>` of `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="aframe-v1.0.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
</html>
```

The library is included in `angular.json`:

```
"scripts": [
  {
    "input": "node_modules/aframe/dist/aframe-v1.0.0.min.js",
    "inject": false,
    "bundleName": "aframe-v1.0.0.min"
  }
]
```

Angular karma tests overwrites `karma.config.js` so the expected overwrites of `customContextFile` do not work as it is overwritten by angular.

In `angular.json`'s `"test"` section the scripts appears to have no effect on the test as well.

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/aframe/dist/aframe-v1.0.0.min.js"
],
```

The test environment would have been inconsistent anyways because the import for the tests would have happened at the body, and not the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.html` file for the karma is located under:

`node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\karma-context.html`
`node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\karma-debug.html`

Once the import for A-Frame is included here (`karma-context.html`), then your unit test will include A-Frame and will run normally:

```
// karma-context.html
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

We can automate this for future tests by creating your own `karma-context.html` and `karma-debug.html`. Under `scripts` directory, create a copy each for both `html` files that includes the A-Frame import. Keep the `karma-context.html` and `karma-debug.html` unmodified in your `node_modules` folder. Changes inside are not propagated when your project is cloned, so our modifications need to live elsewhere.

Create a script that will copy the modified `html` into node_module when karma runs:

```
// scripts/karma-copy.test.js
const fs = require('fs');

// Modify karma-context.html
fs.copyFile(
  'src/scripts/karma-context.html',
  'node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/karma-context.html',
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  }
);

// Modify karma-debug.html
fs.copyFile(
  'src/scripts/karma-debug.html',
  'node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/karma-debug.html',
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  }
);
```

Include the script in `karma.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
  require('../src/scripts/karma-copy.test.js'),
  ...
],
```

Now, when you close your project, `ng t` will include A-Frame in the `<head>`.